# If $\log_ax=2,\log_bx=3,\log_cx=6,$ find $\log_{abc}x = ?$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

$\log_ax=2,\log_bx=3,\log_cx=6,$

$\log_{abc}x = ?$

how can I solve it?

Answer (score 3):

$$x=a^2=b^3=c^6\\
abc=x^{\frac 12}x^{\frac 13}x^{\frac 1 6}=x^{\frac 12+\frac 13+\frac 16}=x\\
\log_{abc}x=\color{red}1$$

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{6}=\log_x{abc}.$$
Thus,
$$\log_{abc}x=\frac{1}{\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{6}}=1$$